# Prefer large titles for single View Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can I set a large title for a single View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller?
Normally I am only able to set large titles for a whole Navigation Controller including all View Controllers but i only want one to display a large title.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Answer (score 14):

While both of the other answers do the trick, a cleaner way to achieve this is by doing the following in the UIViewController you want:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

or for the reverse effect:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

This takes away the need to keep track of a state, which in my opinion is a vast improvement

See [largeTitleDisplayMode - Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2909056-largetitledisplaymode) for more information on the subject

Only downside is that it's iOS 11.0+

Comment: This doesn't work if you've set `prefersLargeTitles` on the Nav bar

Comment: Works like a charm. Set one on first controller and set the other at detail controller.

Answer (score 6):

You can set `prefersLargeTitles = true` in `viewWillAppear` when ViewController's going to appear and `prefersLargeTitles = false` in `viewWillDisappear` when ViewController's going to disappear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the logic for this `viewController` only. You can try something like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place this inside `viewDidLoad()` of the viewController you don't want the large title when it's pushed.
Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // This prevents displaying large title for this vc
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```